# trouble accessing array elements in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So the compiler is telling me that using `[arrayName objectAtIndex:i]` is an invalid expression, yet everything in the documentation is telling me I'm doing it right. I'm confused. Why is it not letting me access an array this way?

```
-(IBAction)textWasEdited:(id)sender
{
   int i = 0;
   do
   {
       //do stuff
       i++
   } while([tipPercentages objectAtIndex:i] != Nil);
}
```

I can't see anything wrong with this code! Kinda pulling my hair out here.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: What about using `for` or `for in` statement?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's a runtime error.

objectAtIndex:number is not returning anything

Comment: @ScubaSteve: If it's a runtime error, then the compiler is not telling you it's an invalid expression, because that would be a compile-time error. Again I ask, what error are you actually getting? Runtime, compile-time, Hammer Time — it doesn't matter. We need an accurate picture of what's happening to tell you what's going wrong with any more accuracy than a random guess.

Comment: the debugger is telling me it's an invalid expression... the program runs but because I can't access array elements to do comparison it just runs out of bounds and dies. Runtime error.

Comment: Very badly asked. In the question you say there's a compiler error; in the comments you say there's no compiler error but rather a runtime error. Then later it turns out there's no runtime error either, but rather you don't understand something the debugger is telling you. Then still later it turns out your real complaint is that the code doesn't work the way you expect. Be polite to your helpers: think and write your question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't have an entirely clear picture of what you're doing here, but I think your problem is that your code keeps trying to access array elements past the end of the array (since `objectAtIndex:` cannot return nil). You want something more like this:

```
- (IBAction)textWasEdited:(id)sender {
   __block int i = 0;
   [tipPercentages enumerateObjectsWithBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       //do stuff
       i++
   }];
}
```

Or, if you really want to maintain the primitive loop:

```
- (IBAction)textWasEdited:(id)sender {
   int i = 0;
   for (; i < [tipPercentages count]; i++) {
       id object = [tipPercentages objectAtIndex:i];
       //do stuff
   }];
}
```

I'm pretty sure whatever you are doing in the debugger that it's rejecting is a side issue — if your code is compiling, the compiler is *not* telling you that your code is invalid.

Comment: Ah you were right. The debugger not evaluating those expressions was a side note. I just had to restructure my loop to not check for Nil.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible that `objectAtIndex:` should return nil, so your code is meaningless. No NSArray can contain nil. And if `tipPercentages` is not an NSArray (for example, if it's a C array), then it can't respond to `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here - chances are that's not an NSArray.

Comment: Ok so why does it demand a sentinal upon initialization? The value at index 3 in that array is Nil. 

Secondly it's evaluating in the debugger [array objectAtIndex:0] to be invalid, so that's not the problem. I was just trying to show an example of it being used.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: The sentinel value is for the argument list. There is no nil in the array.

Comment: ah ok.. but still.. the objectAtIndex method is returning nothing

Comment: If tipPercentages itself is nil, you would see that happen...

Comment: from the debugger:

"[tipOutputs objectAtIndex:0] = invalidExpression"

It's not nil at zero.. Nil isn't the problem.